# iOS: Home/Power Pressed Event

Tags: ios, iphone

If an app is being distributed via Enterprise signing then **is there any framework that allow me to receive `Home` or `Power` pressed events in background?**

Answer (score 1):

All events in iOS are UIEvent that it's a wrapper of GSEvent. With a bit of hacking you should be able to add a callback function of some GSEventRef. [Here there are](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/GraphicsServices/GSEvent.h) the headers of the framework, or just dump it yourself :)

Comment: You are life saviour ;). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately this is not possible, there are no public API's to achieve this, and from my research there doesn't seem to be knowledge of a private API either.